# Get current value of ngrx selector without subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have my ngrx state this way

state.data
state.dataArchived

I would like to copy data from store.data to state.dataArchived.

```
selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulingsByBranch));
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph({}));
  this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$.subscribe(value => {
    this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue = value;
    this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph(this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue));
  });
}
```

the problem is when `state.data` changes, `state.dataArchived` changes too

So I would like to get the current value of `state.data` without subscribing to it.

Comment: Do you only need the first value that is returned by `selectedSchedulingsOnPopup`?

Comment: I need the value when the component is rendered, so I suppose that is the first value when subscribe, and only the first value

Comment: Ahh... In that case this is similar to a question I have previously answered (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419097/10959940). Let me know if it makes sense? If it still doesn't, I will provide an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NgRx Get value without subscribing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296040/ngrx-get-value-without-subscribing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't understand the question, but if you want to get the value without subscribing to it, you can convert it into a promise.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  const data = await this.store.pipe(select(selectorForData),
                               take(1)).toPromise();
}
```

Keep in mind, that in this promise way, it will only react once and get the data and carry on. If you want to be informed of the changes of the data slice, you have to subscribe to it, there is no other way around it.

toPromise is marked as deprecated now. You can use `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom/take(1)` to transform observable into promise as below.

```
async ngOnInit() {
      // firstValueFrom
      const data = await firstValueFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectorForData));
      // lastValueFrom with take(1)
      const data = await lastValueFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectorForData),
                                   take(1)));
}
```

Comment: What I want is getting the current value of data when component is rendered , then if state.data changes ignore the new values , I think as you say by converting it to promise

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the first value and then to ignore all subsequent changes use the first() operator:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph({}));
    this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopup$.pipe(first())
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue = value;
        this.store.dispatch(new GetDirectionsOnGraph(this.selectedSchedulingsOnPopupValue));
      });
  }
```